# Concurrently Load Test Using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, performance-testing

I’m trying to perform a load-test to an external integration environment, using a Lambda function. I want to be able to use `15` concurrent executions of this function to handle thousands of requests and have provided the following config values provoke that;

- `EVENT_BATCH_SIZE = 2 // The number of events that will be grouped together and sent to this microservice at once`
- `EVENT_BATCH_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECS = 1 // The amount of time in seconds that DynamoDB streams will wait before sending the next batch of events to this microservice.`
- `MAX_INSTANCES = 15 // max concurrent lambdas`
- `TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS = 350 // The amount of time in milliseconds that this microservice will wait for a response from the integration api`

I have attempted to send 25,000 events.

However, it appears the concurrent executions never go beyond `5`, which brings the requests/min rate quite low and not really suitable for load testing… any suggestions on how to force Lambda to use all of the `"ReservedConcurrentExecutions": 15`, other than increasing the amount of events created to a huge number?

[image: metrics]

Comment: Is the Lambda function behind an API gateway, or how are you invoking it?

Comment: @Maurice it's not behind any API gateway, I'm invoking it by running a script that executes a POST request N number of times.

Comment: Is your script fast enough and using the invocation type event? Lambda will only scale out as much as necessary to handle the number of events.

Comment: You mentioned DynamoDB Streams. Are you triggering the Lambda functions by inserting/updating DynamoDB items?